# Why am I wrong with my index of coincidence program in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography

I made a program to calculate the index of coincidence but it seems to be wrong. I don't know where my error is.

---

**My program :**

```
import string

def apparitions(chaine) :
    app = [0] * 26
    for c in chaine :
        if c in string.ascii_uppercase :
            app[ord(c) - ord('A')] += 1
    return app

def indice_coincidence(chaine) :
    app = apparitions(chaine) 
    s = sum (n*(n-1) for n in app)
    somme = sum(app)
    return s / (somme*(somme-1))

PP_texte = open('PP.txt', 'r')
P=PP_texte.read()

print(indice_coincidence(P))
```

---

I tried my program with the [Little Prince by Antoine de Saint Exupéry](http://lepetitprinceexupery.free.fr/telecharger/le-petit-prince--antoine-de-saint-exupery.txt), in French (because i am) and my program return `0.08413880573688703`.

I know that in french the index is approx 0.074. So tried on a [reference website about cryptography](http://www.apprendre-en-ligne.net/crypto/stat/ic.html) and the answer is `0.07446`

---

As a conclusion my pragram must be wrong. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Don't you need *two* texts for IC?

Comment: I'm looking at the [equation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_coincidence). Aren't you supposed to divide by "the normalizing coefficient" somewhere?

Comment: @ArtjomB., if that's the answer, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @Kevin the OP is doing that on the line `return s / (somme*(somme-1))`

Comment: @Kevin the OP is going based off of the definition given on the cryptography site which is different from the one on wikipedia.

Comment: @MichaelSPriz Wikipedia also mentions this: *"Sometimes values are reported without the normalizing denominator, for example 0.067=1.73/26 for English"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try printing your letter frequency array and comparing it with the one on the website :)

When I do that with your code I get:

[image: Python Output]

Which is far from what the website says. With a little debugging you will see that you are only checking for uppercase letters!

My fix was to change your for loop to this:

```
for c in chaine.upper() :
    if c in string.ascii_uppercase :
        app[ord(c) - ord('A')] += 1
```

Which gave the expected output :)

NOTE: Neither your code nor the website considers an accented letter to be part of "the alphabet". For instance 'é' is not counted at all!

Comment: No problem! Good luck with the rest of the project!

Comment: Thank you, I'm doing my own software for cryptography. Then I will have exactly what I want ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself a lot of trouble and use `collections.Counter` to count how often a letter appears.

```
In [1]: import collections

In [2]: collections.Counter('This is a test with accented characters à é ó ú ü')
Out[2]: Counter({' ': 11, 't': 5, 'e': 4, 's': 4, 'c': 4, 'a': 4, 'i': 3, 'h': 3, 'r': 2, 'd': 1, 'ó': 1, 'ú': 1, 'T': 1, 'w': 1, 'é': 1, 'ü': 1, 'à': 1, 'n': 1})
```